# executeQuery Exits Immediately

Tags: sql, jdbc, sybase

I'm using Sybase and I've ran into an issue that I can't seem to resolve. I have a query like this

```
SELECT * FROM A, B 
WHERE A.someField = B.someField
AND A.otherField = ?
```

otherField is defined as Char(2)

If I substitute ? with '11' for example everything works fine but if I instead substitute a String with an alpha character such as "D1" then executeQuery doesn't seem to do anything. I've put a breakpoint when executeQuery gets called and with the alpha string  parameter after executeQuery executes, it immediately exits without calling any code after the statement, it doesn't hang or throw any exception. Has anybody ran into this issue before?

Comment: If I saw this in the environments i use, I'd be checking the list of ignored exception types in the ide's debugger setup, probably for ole exception.

Comment: Try putting a try catch block around your executeQuery .Catch Throwable and do a print stack trace.You will not the error